# leftflush author's affiliation, but not author, in `authblk`

Tags: titles, authblk

In the following MWE, I want to flush left the author's `affil`iation, but not the title or the author's name. 
Furthermore, I need to be able to add paragraphs in the `affil`-environment.
How can this be achieved?

```
\documentclass[12pt,abstract,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\linespread{2}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}% not special font for page head and foot
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\begin{document}

\markright{Running Head: This header to be only on title page}
\titlehead{\thispagestyle{headings}}
\title{mytitle}
\author{Donald Duck}
\affil{Entenhausen University, Department of Ornithological Affairs, 
Chair of Breadcrumb Allocation Optimization. 
Correspondence on this article should be directed addressed to: 
Donald Duck, 251 Pond Blvd, 90210 Ducky \\ Contact: donald.duck@yahoo.com}

\maketitle

\markright{This header to appear from abstract page onward}
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{headings}
Abstract text...
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Begin text here.

\end{document}
```

It should look close to this sample I received:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write a document following the rules of the American Psychological Association, just use a suitable class. Namingly `apa6`. Everything is already defined and ready to use.

[image: maiepApaTitle]

```
\documentclass[man,12pt]{apa6}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\title{Investigating the Relationship between Quails and Ducks with special respect of mating rituals}
\shorttitle{Relationship between Quails and Ducks in mating}
\author{Donald Duck}
\affiliation{Entenhausen University, Department of Ornithological Affairs, 
Chair of Breadcumb Allocation Optimization. }
\authornote{Correspondence on this article should be directed addressed to: 
Donald Duck, 251 Pond Blvd, 90210 Ducky \\ Contact: donald.duck@yahoo.com}
\abstract{\blindtext
}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```